# Get WASD keys to follow camera rotation in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, trigonometry

I understand there are many answers to this online but I was unable to apply them correctly to my code.
I have tried using pre-made player assets but could not get that to work.

```
    Vector3 pos = transform.position;

    public float X;
    public float Y;
    public float Z;

// Used to tilt camera up and down
float tilt = 0;

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
    {
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * panSpeed, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * panSpeed, 0));
        X = transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x;
        Y = transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y;
        Z = transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z;
        // Add current position of mouse input
        tilt += X;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, Y, tilt);
    }

    //Spaceship does not go in direction it is facing once panned
    if (Input.GetKey("w"))
    {
        //transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, Y, tilt);
        pos.z += speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    if (Input.GetKey("s"))
    {
        pos.z -= speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    if (Input.GetKey("d"))
    {
        pos.x += speed * Time.deltaTime;
        // DEBUG Does not work properly while mouse held down
        //transform.Rotate(-1, 0, 0);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey("a"))
    {
        pos.x -= speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    transform.position = pos;
```

Comment: You want wsad to move relative to the camera direction?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming here the "Camera" equals `transform` you can simply use its local axis [`transform.forward`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-forward.html)

> Returns a normalized vector representing the blue axis of the transform in world space.

and [`transform.right`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-right.html)

> Returns a normalized vector representing the red axis of the transform in world space.

like e.g.

```
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
    {
        // NOTE: I DON'T UNDERSTAND THIS CODE BLOCK YET
        // YOU KNOW E.G. THAT IF YOU "transform.eulerAngles.x" ALREADY IS "45°"
        // THE "tilt" WOULD JUMP EVERY FRAME IN HUGER STEPS (45 -> 90 -> 180 - 360 ....)

        // ALSO WHY ROTATE IN X AXIS IF AFTERWARDS YOU RESET THE X ROTATION
        // AND RATHER APPLY IT TO Z?

        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * panSpeed, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * panSpeed, 0));
        X = transform.eulerAngles.x;
        Y = transform.eulerAngles.y;
        Z = transform.eulerAngles.z;
        // Add current position of mouse input
        tilt += X;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, Y, tilt);
    }

    Vector3 movement = Vector3.zero;

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        movement += transform.forward;
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
    {
        movement -= transform.forward;
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    {
        movement += transform.right;
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
        movement -= transform.right;
    }

    // I would do it like this to make sure that diagonal movement 
    // does not move faster
    transform.position = movement.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

Comment: I have never worked with transform.eulerAngles before and even after reading the api I am still confused. I borrowed all the code but the "tilt += X;" which I added to the last parameter of rotation which through trial and error gave me the outcome I wanted. I'm not sure how, but it worked. I tried using only your code and mixing it in with my current code and was unable to get my camera to move with "movement += / -=" it seems only "pos. " can move my camera